# Find document $in with string array Mongoose match all the text cases

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am currently working with MERN stack for an E-commerce website

I am finding a syntax in Mongoose like:

```
Product.find({ brands: {$in : ["Brand1", "brand2", "BRAND3"], $option: 'match all cases'}})
```

I expect the result will match all Products that have brand1 or Brand1 or BRAND1, Brand2 or brand2, and so on...

How can I solve it in Mongoose v6.0.13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to execute in mongoDB compass use below query

```
Product.find({brands :{$in:[new RegExp('brand1', 'i'), new RegExp('brand2', 'i')]}} )
```

If using mongoose use

```
Product.find({ brands:{$in:[{ $regex: new RegExp('brand1', "i") }, { $regex: new RegExp('brand2', "i") }] })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass brand name in quotes.

```
Product.find({ brands: {$in : ["Brand1", "brand2", "BRAND3"], $option: 'match all cases'}})
```

to make case insensitive search,

```
var brands = [/^Brand1$/i,/^brand2$/i,/^BRAND3$/i];
Product.find({ brands: {$in : brands}})
```

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

let regex = brands.join("|");
Product.find({ brands: { $regex: regex, $options: 'i' });

Thank you everyone for helping

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).